# setDT - group by over all columns in a vector

Tags: r

Imagine one has a table X, with 10 columns Col1 - Col5. Col5 is column with amounts. With setDT I can compute the sum of Col5 over the unique Col1-Col4 combinations:

```
setDT(X)[,list(sum(Col5)), 
          by = .(Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4)]
```

Is there a way to prevent having to list every Col1-4 in the by statement and instead for instance use a vector that identifies all the group by columns?

This for instance doesn't work for obvious reasons:

```
setDT(X)[,list(sum(Col5)), 
          by = .(colnames(X[,-c(5)]))]
```

I don't want to use the aggregate function because it turns everything in factors.

Comment: You can also use `by = c(names(X)[1:4])` or `by = c(names(X)[-5])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `paste0`.

```
setDT(X)[,list(sum(Col5)), by = .(c(paste0("Col",1:4)))]
```

Comment: I had to change the code a bit for it to work

    setDT(X)[,list(sum(Col5)), by = eval(paste0("Col",1:4))]

Thanks though